# Get list of all resources of roster entry

Tags: xmpp, smack

I want to get a list of all (active) resources of a person in my roster. 
So for example "user1@gmail.com" I'd like to get something like `{'gmail', 'pidgin'}` if that user was currently logged in via GMail ('user1@gmail.com/gmail') and Pidgin.

Is this possible with Smack? I know that some clients show this information and e.g. XMPPHP supports something like `getResources()`, but XMPPHP is for PHP and doesn't work for Google Talk so that doesn't help me much.

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Smack you need to track Presence packets as they are received. The "from" of the received packets will contain the resources for the JIDs of users.

For example:

```
private XMPPConnection connection;
private PresenceListener listener = new PresenceListener();

public void setConnection(XMPPConnection connection) {
    this.connection = connection;
}

public void createPresenceListener() {
    connection.addPacketListener(listener, new PacketTypeFilter(Presence.class));
}

public static class PresenceListener implements PacketListener {
    public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
        Presence presence = (Presence) packet;
        if (presence.getType() == null || presence.getType() == Presence.Type.available) {
            String from = presence.getFrom();
            if (from != null && from.lastIndexOf("/") > 0) {
                String resource = from.substring(from.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                // from here you can track all active resources
            }
        }

    }
}
```